# Can we create .csv file with a Batch Apex

Tags: batch

Can we create a batch class where we can query the records and generate a .csv file .

I have to automate the process and team is not interest in having a server where i can host the Command line Data loader and schedule it with window scheduler. I can't store it attachment or somewhere. I have to copy that .csv file to FTP Location.

The purpose behind this is remove the server that we needed to host command line dataloader...

Thanks

Comment: I am also interested in this but I would like to know whether we will be able to create a formatted excel file instead of .csv

Comment: With Excel you can just generate a HTML file with a table containing the data. If you give it the right mimetype (I forget what it is off the top of my head) it'll work a treat.

Answer (score 3):

You could definitely generate one where you then store the body of it in an attachment/document and then retrieve it later on, though it might be worth checking that you really need to do that. Oftentimes using an integration tool or dataload is enough in these circumstances, where you can extract data via CSV directly. If you need some processing to be done you could do that with the batch and store the data in a new object ready for export (record per row).

Comment: We have a batch process that does indeed generate CSV files on exports larger than a defined size (1k rows). It's easy to do, really.

Comment: Thanks  @LaceySnr.   I have to automate the process and team is not interest in having a server where i host the Dataloader and schedule it with window scheduler.  I can't store it attachment or somewhere.  I have to copy that file to FTP Location ... .  Can i query that data ,generate a .csv and copy it to share location with Batch APEX.

Comment: You won't be able to FTP from a batch. You're going to need something somewhere either pulling that data out or hosting a webservice to receive it.